# How to highlight one specific UIMenuItem in UIMenuController programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I know this might sounds not reasonable, and might be a bad design.
But I want to know is there any way that I can programmatically highlight one of the UIMenuitem when a UIMenuController pop-up?

i.e. Just like the state when I 'press down' that item but before 'press up', it will have a blue background indicate what I pressed.

Just like I can use following code for UIButton

```
[myBtn setHighlighted:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is certainly no easy / app store safe way, `UIMenuItem`s are not even `UIView` subclasses, so you cannot subclass and implement your own drawing code.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't .. to do that you need to build your own menuView and present it instead of UIMenuController.